# Excel Create a function that counts the number of "s" in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

I have to create a function that counts and shows in one cellm the times that the "s" character appears in a row range in Excel. It has to be robust enough since many times the "s" character can appear with hundreds of combinations, so doing `=COUNTIFS(C4:AG4;"s";C4:AG4;"sc"...)` wouldn't work.

I decided to write `=LEN(C3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3;"s";""))` and it is robust enough to only count the times that s is said in each cell. I could simply copy paste that function and change the argument to D4,F4,G4,H4... and do a summation of it all, but I think it is not an elegant solution. Anyone has a better idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT() it will iterate through the row and count each cell and add them together.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(C3:AG3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3:AG3;"s";"")))
```

Or if you have Office 365:

```
=LEN(CONCAT(C3:AG3))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(C3:AG3);"s";""))
```

Comment: Woah that works great, I didn't know about the SUMPRODUCT function, it will surely come in handy in the future, thank you very much.

Comment: @Marco if this worked for you please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.